# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java

I have made a program to calculate area of **square circle and rectangle**

```
int W=0;
int X=0;
int Y=0;
int Z=0;
int A1=0;
int A2=0;
int A3=0;
```

//take input from user

```
String A=TF1.getText();
String B=TF2.getText();
String C=TF3.getText();
String D=TF4.getText();
```

//convert it into integer

```
W=Integer.parseInt(A);
X=Integer.parseInt(B);
Y=Integer.parseInt(C);
Z=Integer.parseInt(D);
```

//use the values to calculate the area

```
  A1=W*W;
  A2=X*Y;
  A3=(3*Z*Z);
```

//and display according to the option selected

```
if (RB1.isSelected())
TF5.setText(" "+A1);
else if(RB3.isSelected())
TF5.setText(" "+A2);
else
TF5.setText(" "+A3);
```

//also I have made some text fields invisible according to the option the user has selected

Comment: Thumb rule : Before parsing, check for null and empty.

Comment: If user inputs nothing or a string, there would be number format exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Follow coding conventions while naming so that it is easy to comprehend the code.
For example, `String firstNumberString = firstTextBox.getText();` would look far better to read instead of `String A=TF1.getText();`

2) You are retrieving text from each textbox and trying to parse it. But if the textbox contains nothing, the `Integer.parseInt()` method will throw a `NumberFormatException` which is happening in your case.

Solution : validate the text in the TextBox.

```
private Boolean validateText(String str)
{
 if ( str == null || str.equals("") ) {
                return false;
            }

            char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
            boolean ok = true;

            for ( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ) {

                try {
                    Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf( chars[i] ) );
                } catch ( NumberFormatException exc ) {
                    ok = false;
                    break;
                }


            }

           return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert the empty `string` into a number. If the user doesn't enter anything in the `textfield`, your code will retrieve the empty string from the textfield, and then try to convert it with `Integer.parseInt`.

You need to start by checking that all the fields are non-empty; or, put a `try/catch` around the whole thing, and abort the calculation if you catch a `NumberFormatException`.

When you do catch the `exception`, you can issue a warning to the user that the input is invalid.